# resize:vertical issue for iframe in Mozilla

Tags: iframe

I have used "resize:vertical" for re-sizing my i frame tag vertically. I have given "overflow:auto" to iframe tag.It is completely working in Google chrome but it is not working in Mozilla. Can somebody help me with this issue?

Note : I have used Kendo HTML editor.There is a iframe tag inside it.